# Looking for substitutes for some functionality while moving from Netty 3.x to 4.21 final

Tags: java, netty

In  Netty 3.5 we use  SimpleChannelHandler, which provides method for both event types. How do I use the same approach in Netty 4.0.0?
To be more specific i m looking for a substitute of the method below

```
public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws       Exception {

}
```

I am trying to send message to all clients connected to the server.
Here is the example for netty 3.x

```
ChannelGroup allConnected = new DefaultChannelGroup("all-connected");

@Override
public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws     Exception {
super.channelConnected(ctx, e);
allConnected.add(e.getChannel());
```

}

and then to send messages to all channels connected

```
ChannelBuffer cb = ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer("hello".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
allConnected.write(cb);
```

This is what i need to do in Netty 4.21 final but i couldn't find a similar method which provided me the needed functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you mean by **both event types**. I guess you mean client and server? I use `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` for that:

```
public class ServerCommunicationHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    private final ChannelGroup channels = new DefaultChannelGroup(GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        channels.add(ctx.channel());
        ctx.fireChannelActive();
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        broadcastMessage(msg);
        ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        channels.remove(ctx.channel());
        ctx.fireChannelInactive();
    }

    public void broadcastMessage(Object object) {
        channels.writeAndFlush(object);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am quite new at netty so i might be wrong on this but in the above code snippet i couldn't understand that how would "brodcastMessage()" method be called.

Comment: how did you do call your `allConnected.write(cb);` in the old version?

Comment: added a little example (`channelRead`). This will broadcast the message to all connected clients (including sender) as soon as a new message is received.

Comment: sorry as i said that i am newbie so got confused. I have to write this to a websocket so will the same technique work just by replacing    channels.writeAndFlush(object); with    channel.writeAndFlush(new TextWebSocketFrame(object); and thanks for your help.

Comment: maybe this example can help you. https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/websocketx

Comment: the changes I mentioned prior to your comment worked. Thanks a lot.